# touch событие для highcharts series point events?

Tags: highcharts

Как вызвать событие click для мобильных устройств?
А настольном браузере всё работает. А в мобильной сама карта выделяет регион, но события click нет.

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        point: {

          events: {
            click: function(e, s, d) {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```